# datepicker specified value does not conform to the required format jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So yesterday I asked a question about setting the date for a calendar. I was missing some references so have since added them. Please see the HTML section below.

I believe my code to be correct for how to set the date for a calendar. However upon loading the page I get these errors,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token datepicker.css:11
>
> The specified value "09/01/2018" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd". 
>   jquery.js:8254

Not sure why this is not working and where the date "09/01/2018" is coming from at all?

I also think in my  the datepicker.css should be like below.

> link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

When I do this the Uncaught SyntaxError message disappears but still have the other issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker();
  $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018, 8, 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" />

<input id="dtSelectorStatic" />
```

**Update**

Below are all the references I have in my page. One thing (might be nothing) but when I type "script src=" the intelli sense picks on my folder scripts and list 3 files (image below, jQES is the file I created) but it does not list the other two files also in that folder, jquery-ui.js or jquery-ui.min.js

[image: script folder in visual studio]

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'table'] });
</script>
<script src="/scripts/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jQES.js"></script> 
<link href="CSS/MyCSSFile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
```

**update 2**

This is how it looks on load up.

[image: on load up]

If I click in the area where the blue arrow is pointing to the calendar below is shown.

[image: click in the area where the blue arrow is pointing to]

If I click on the big black arrow I get both calendars

[image: big arrow]

I have another calendar box which is exactly the same. Which only shows the calendar shown below no matter what I do. The only difference is that on load up I do not try to set the date as I do in the calendar above.

```
   <input id="someId" type="date"/>
```

[image: normal calendar]

Comment: I cant reproduce the error. Does your input have a default value? And did you specify a custom `dateFormat` in your datepicker code?

Comment: @SalmanA To be honest I'm just testing using the datepicker. So in my $(document).ready(function... I am just trying to set the date with the two lines of code in my post. I feel like the issue is maybe to do with the references in my html head

Comment: What's your problem exactly? Is this code not working for you?

Comment: @chŝdk yes when I load my page the date picker is not showing me the date I specified, just has text mm / dd / yyyy showing. Debugging the page I get a warning saying... jquery.js:8254 The specified value "08/01/2018" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: I'm guessing I'm referencing the wrong library or something

Comment: So now (after update 1) you're using jquery-ui datepicker, am I right? Have you cleared cache?

Comment: @barbsan yes I want to use the jquery-ui datepicker. How do I clear the cache? Read you can just press ctrl + f5 when the page has loaded

Comment: @mHelpMe sometimes ctrl+f5 is not enough, see instructions for [chrome](https://superuser.com/a/722548) and [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox)

Comment: @barbsan oh I see, just did the "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" but still no difference?

Comment: Your proplem is similar to this [issue](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker/issues/129). Try changing input type from `date` to `text`

Comment: ah sorry github is blocked on my work pc... like to challenge us

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jquery-ui datepicker [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#options) (scroll at least 1 line up, there's no id on Additional Notes, that was the closest element I could link to) contains information about this issue:

> Additional Notes: 
>   ...
>
> **Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.**

This is default HTML5 input with attribute `type="date"`:

```html
<input type="date">
```

From MDN about HTML5 date input's [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value):

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the actual value — the **displayed date format will be chosen based on the set locale of the user's browser**, whereas the **date value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd**.

When you add jquery-ui datepicker, you see both of them. 
 What's worse its default value format is `yyyy-mm-dd` (see more [on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support)) so if you change format jquery-ui datepicker sets value formatted as in `dateFormat` property (or based on locales). It starts showing warning (not visible in snippet's console, propably console.warn is only visible in developer tools)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-M-yy"});

  $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018, 8, 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />


<input type="date" id="dtSelectorStatic" />
```

Possible fix: if you remove attribute `type="date"` or set it to `"text"` then you get functionality of jquery-ui datepicker (see snippet below).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});

  $("#dtSelectorStatic").datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018, 8, 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />


<input id="dtSelectorStatic" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The date thing now makes sense, keep forgetting the date is zero based. I have updated my post with some further information to do with the references

Comment: thanks very much it is now working. Still unsure why changing the type from date to text works, seems illogical

Comment: @mHelpMe I've updated answer - there's note in docs that this plugin is incompatible with date input.

Comment: I have been fighting with this datepicker for a couple of days now. removing the type=date completely solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any jquery or special date library for fixing it. Simple JS will do just fine. The problem is that the browser requires the format yyyy-mm-dd.

And toLocaleString doesn't allow the date to be in this format. So after searching I found out that this is ISO format and we can use Date().toISOString() to get the date in the required format.

I used the slice method to extract the date part only because Date().toISOString() returns date with time.

My code: `date: new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)`

Answer (score 0):

Try  this trick

```
$("#datePicker").datepicker();

var qDate = '2018-08-01';

$('.datepicker').datepicker({ 
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
     }).datepicker("setDate", new Date(qDate));
```

Comment: Still the same message,  The specified value "09/01/2018" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd". jquery.js:8254

Comment: still the same unfortuantely

Comment: Try this exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/542943/ and i just adjust the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this if need any help please comment.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018, 8, 1));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<input type="text" class="datepicker" /><br/>
<style>
    .ui-datepicker {font-size:60%; }
</style>
```

Comment: when I change from #datepicker to .datepicker the calendar still does not show my date but there are no error messages

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd" 
   });
  $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date(2018, 8, 1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/3ow88r6u/291/

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/blitzer/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form method="post">
    <p><input type="date" placeholder="" /></p>
</form>
```